# discord py: canceling a loop using a command

Tags: python, discord.py

My question is this: If I were to make a command with a loop (for example "start") where it would say something like:"It has been 3 hours since..." and it loops for 10800 seconds (3 hours) and then says:"It has been 6 hours since..." , so the part where I'm stuck is: If I were to make a command called "stop" how would I implement it in the command "start" where it would check if the command "stop" has been used. If yes the loop is cancelled, if it hasn't been used the loop continues.

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.command()
async def startloop(self, ctx):
  self.isrunning = True
  await ctx.send("Starting loop.")

  while self.isrunning:
    # do stuff here
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

@bot.command()
async def stoploop(self, ctx):
  self.isrunning = False

  await ctx.send("Stopped loop.")
```

Just define a variable in your instance (in my example `self.isrunning`) and check against that.

Answer (score 0):

but if you run the command several times or on different servers, one stop command stops them all. Is there not a way to stop just one loop with one command